# Ember.js, throttle REST adapter calls

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am using Parse, which only allows 30 reqs/sec to their backend.

Therefore, I'd like to throttle all calls going to Parse via the REST adapter (specifically the [ember-parse-adapter](https://github.com/clintjhill/ember-parse-adapter), which extends the `DS.RESTAdapter`).

I tried throttling the `ajax` method, which I assumed needed to return a Promise:

```
export default ParseAdapter.extend({
    applicationId: ENV.APP.applicationId,
    restApiId: ENV.APP.restApiId,

    ajax: function(url, type, options) {
        var self = this;
        return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            Ember.run.later(this,resolve,5000); // I would prefer this to be Ember.run.throttle, but not sure if that will work
        }).then(function() {
            return self._super(url,type,options)
        });
    }

});
```

However I get this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'results' of undefined
    at exports.default.DS.default.RESTSerializer.extend.extractArray (vendor.js:115817)
    at apply (vendor.js:30197)
    at superWrapper (vendor.js:29749)
    at ember$data$lib$system$serializer$$default.extend.extractFindAll (vendor.js:81161)
    at ember$data$lib$system$serializer$$default.extend.extract (vendor.js:81144)
    at superFunction [as _super] (vendor.js:25863)
    at exports.default.DS.default.RESTSerializer.extend.extract (vendor.js:115843)
    at apply (vendor.js:30197)
    at superWrapper [as extract] (vendor.js:29749)
```

What can I do to throttle the REST Adapter?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to batch API requests together?

I don't know the best way to do this myself, however a good place to start looking might be this Ember CLI plugin, '[ember-model-batch](https://github.com/jayphelps/ember-model-batch)'

[Direct link to source code](https://github.com/jayphelps/ember-model-batch/blob/master/ember-model-batch.js)